# Vue/vuetify, how to add router link to tab

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I would like to use the vuetify tab component simply as a navigation control, to

```
 <v-tabs dark fixed icons centered>
    <v-tabs-bar class="cyan">
      <v-tabs-slider color="yellow"></v-tabs-slider>
      <v-tabs-item router :to="{name: 'election/admin', id: this.$route.params['id']}">
        Overview
      </v-tabs-item>
    </v-tabs-bar>

  </v-tabs>
```

However, it doesn't seem t obe working. I thought that the `to` property in addition with `router` should work to replace href?

Comment: `<v-tabs-item  :to="{name: 'RouteName'}">`, so no need for `router` option anymore. However I think it's possible that your route `name` is not `election/admin`, so that's probably an error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT 2018/11/15**
Added new example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQqjKe?editors=1011)

```
<v-tabs v-model="activeTab">
  <v-tab v-for="tab in tabs" 
         :key="tab.name" 
         :to="{name: tab.name, params: id}"
  >
    {{tab.text}}
  </v-tab>
</v-tabs>

data: () => ({
  activeTab: "",
  tabs: [
    { name: "UserProfile", text: "Profile" }, 
    { name: "UserActivity", text: "Activity" },
    { name: "UserSettings", text: "Settings" },
  ],
}),
```

---

*Note*:
this answer worked for older `vuetify` version.
Tabs syntax has changed since then, and now in `v1` looks like:

```
<v-tabs>
    <v-tab>Tab 1</v-tab>
    <v-tab>Tab 2</v-tab>
    <v-tab-item>Tab 1 content</v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item>Tab 2 content</v-tab-item>
</v-tabs>
```

Answer still applies, but on `v-tab` element, instead of `v-tabs-item`
e.g. `<v-tab :to="{path:'/path/to/somewhere'}">`

---

**Answer:**

Use either:

```
<v-tabs-item :to="{path:'/path/to/somewhere'}">
```

Or

```
<v-tabs-item :to="{name:'RouteName'}">
```

Notice `path` vs `name`

You can use `name` if you are using [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html)

AFAIK you can't pass `props` if you are not using `named route`, thus you must name it and then

```
:to="{name: 'RouteName', params: {id: $route.params['id'] }}"
```

Also notice that params must  be inside `params` object